# json.net and TypeNameSerializationBinder: BindToType is never called

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

When I create a class deriving from *SerializationBinder* and use that when serializing to or from JSON (using json.net in C#), one method in *TypeNameSerializationBinder* is never called, and as I can see it, never used at all.

In other words: the serializationbinder method BindToName is never called, and I don't get why.

This is the derived class:

```
public class TypeNameSerializationBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    public string TypeFormat { get; private set; }

    public TypeNameSerializationBinder(string typeFormat)
    {
        TypeFormat = typeFormat;
    }

    public override void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
    {
        assemblyName = serializedType.FullName; // <-- BREAKPOINT HERE
        typeName = ""; // serializedType.Name;
    }

    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        string resolvedTypeName = string.Format(TypeFormat, typeName);
        Type t = Type.GetType(resolvedTypeName, true); // <-- BREAKPOINT HERE
        return t;
    }
}
```

and then a helper class:

```
public class JSONHandler
{
    public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
            Binder = new TypeNameSerializationBinder("MyProtocol.{0}")
        });
        return json;
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
    {
        T t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
            Binder = new TypeNameSerializationBinder("MyProtocol.{0}")
        });
        return t;        }
}
```

And lastly, this is where I call the helper class to serialize and deserialize:

```
var resource = new Resource() { ResourceProperty = "Resource" };
var video = new Video() { ResourceProperty = "Video", VideoProperty = "VideoMP4", TapeProperty = new Tape() { SomeOtherValue = "asd", SomeValue = 123 } };
var list = new List<Resource>() { resource, video };

string serialistedList = JSONHandler.Serialize<List<Resource>>(list);
List<Resource> newList = JSONHandler.Deserialize<List<Resource>>(serialistedList);
```

I need to understand why the BindToName is never called. BindToType is called on deserialization though.

Dummy classes:

```
public class Resource
{
    public string ResourceProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Video : Resource
{
    public string VideoProperty { get; set; }
    public Tape TapeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Tape
{
    public int SomeValue { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherValue { get; set; }
}
```

### Edit

Brian Rogers said that it does work, and linked to .NET Fiddle (see below). It look in .NET Fiddle as it does call the BindToName, but in my solution it most definitely does not:

[image]

Comment: [It does get called](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RPCvHY).

Comment: Well, its not called when I run it, thats for sure... See updated post =)

Comment: Have you tried running the Fiddle code in your local environment to see if it works there?

Comment: So, I was running with version 4.5.9 of Newtonsoft. If I updated to the latest, 6.0.x, then the BindToName is executed... So, is this a bug in older versions?

Comment: However, if I try .NET FIddle, with json.net v 4.5.9, it works in .NET Fiddle too... Weird, very weird.

Comment: I don't know whether it is a bug in older versions or not.  You'd have to go through the change history.  But at least it sounds like you are on your way now, so that is good!